# Java Rest Client using Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a java  Rest Client which will keep post data to java Rest Service

I have developed jersey client code to post data to Rest Service.
when i execute My Client application

1. It will connect to the database and it will execute select query
2. It will connect to the Rest service URL and it will post the data

My code:

```
select * from Workorder

for(int i =0;i<workorderList.size(); i++){

   WorkOrder workorder=workorderLit.get(i);

   WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://localhost:8013/Workorderrest/rest/inbound/update");

   ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                    .type("application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonData);   
}
```

I want to change the status flag in my table column to processed when I receive  response from Rest Service

Could any one please.I want to post data using Multiple threads
any suggestions

Comment: ***If you want multiple threads you need to create them !*** here you haven't code for it

Comment: Read up on using `ExecutorService` and `Callable` in java.

Answer (score 2):

I tried and below one is working for me...

*ClientThread.java*

```
package com.test;

    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

    public class ClientThread extends Thread{

    Client client = null;
    WebResource resource = null;

    public ClientThread()
    {
        client = Client.create();
        resource = client.resource("http://localhost:9080/RestfulHelloExample/rest/hello/kumar");

    }
    public void run()
    {
        ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                 + response.getStatus());
        }

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);             
    }
    }
```

*TestClient.java*

```
public class TestClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClientThread t1 = new ClientThread();
    ClientThread t2 = new ClientThread();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}

}
```

let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

after getting response

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, jsonData);
```

try this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                       throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
                }else{
                    // your code for updating status flag in table 
                }
            }
}).start();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: i was assuming this guy know threads but if not then i have updated my answer according to threads :)